# DATEDIFF в SQL не высчитывает разницу в днях

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не корректно работает условие WHERE:

```
SELECT Klienti.Familiya, Zakazi.Data_zakaza
FROM Zakazi
INNER JOIN Klienti ON Zakazi.Kod_klienta=Klienti.Kod_klienta;
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, Zakazi.Data_vozvrata, Zakazi.Data_zakaza)) > 3;
```

При попытке запустить выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку.
Тип полей Zakazi.Data_vozvrata, Zakazi.Data_zakaza - DATE
(Если закомментировать блок WHERE, то ошибок нет)

Comment: поменять вместо дата заказа и дата возврат и пожалуйста напишите детальную информацию.

Comment: Укажите с какой БД работаете. И попробуйте так `WHERE (DATEDIFF(dd, Zakazi.Data_vozvrata, Zakazi.Data_zakaza)) > 3;` И ошибку тоже добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @RasulHuseynov уже менял, ничего не помогло. также вместо day подставлял dd, d...

Comment: У вас еще точка с запятой перед `Where` стоит.

Comment: @lDrakonl поменял и ничего... я написал БД в LibreOffice Base ( там вроде SQL)

Comment: @lDrakonl я её убрал. Ошибка не ушла. Состояние SQL: S0022
Код ошибки: -28

Comment: У меня дурацкий вопрос. Вы уверены, что делаете в LibreOffice, а не Microsft Accsess ?

Comment: Попробуйте такие варианты: `DATEDIFF('dd', Zakazi.Data_vozvrata, Zakazi.Data_zakaza)`, `DATEDIFF('d', Zakazi.Data_vozvrata, Zakazi.Data_zakaza)`, `DATEDIFF( Zakazi.Data_vozvrata; Zakazi.Data_zakaza;"d")`

Comment: @lDrakonl помогли одинарные кавычки. спасибо =)